# ATSAM4LC2B USB reference schematics?

Tags: usb

I am using the ATSAM4LC2B in a project, it says it supports USB but I can't find any thing showing which pins are dedicated for the USB, the data sheet says it has Host + Device, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [ATSAM4L schematic checklist](http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-42025-at01777-sam4l-schematic-checklist_application-note.pdf) and the datasheet Mario linked to. It seems the pins you're looking for are PA25 and PA26 (Table 3-2 in the datasheet).

Answer (score 1):

It's in the [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-42023-ARM-Microcontroller-ATSAM4L-Low-Power-LCD_Datasheet.pdf). Section 3 "Package and Pinout".

See the application notes for examples.

You could also have a look at an eval board. The [User Guide](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj118vLvZrLAhUqG5oKHbWACWAQFggeMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.atmel.com%2Fimages%2Fatmel-42074-sam4l-xplained-pro_user-guide.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEOi1oq6kPvCFjbOjKn-fhKdagFcA) contains a link to the schematics.

Comment: nothing about USB? just the pins and package